# Make a table column editable and save in a file

Tags: javascript, datatables, jeditable

I'm trying to make a table column editable but I'm not very familiar with JS so can someone show me the light please ? 
To save the file I've found a jquery plugin which is great.
But for Editing and saving I didn't find a way to do it...

```
$(document).ready(function() {
    /* Init DataTable */
    var table2Edit = $('#table2Edit').dataTable(); 

    // Save table in json file
    var table = $('#table2Edit').tableToJSON();        
    $.ajax({
        type : "POST",
        url : "ajax.php",
        dataType : 'json', 
        data : {
          json : JSON.stringify(table) /* convert here only */
        }
    });
} );
```

Server Side:

```
 $json = $_POST['json'];
            if (json_decode($json) != null) { /* sanity check */
                $file = fopen('myTable.json','w+');
                fwrite($file, $json);
                fclose($file);
                var_dump($file);
    }
```

Answer (score 0):

Use the DataTables [Editor plugin](http://editor.datatables.net/)